# (2n + 1) + (2n) is odd?

Tags: proof-explanation

I'm looking at basic proofs in *Lang* and in *Downing*. Here's the proof in question in *Downing*:

$m$ and $n$ are natural numbers $\ne 0$.

$$s = (2n) + (2m + 1)$$
$$s = 2(m + n) + 1$$
Thus the answer is odd by an earlier definition of odd as $2n + 1$.
This seems to me like just selectively applying the rules to get an answer you want. Why can't I just rewrite this as
$s = 2(m + n + 1)$ by associativity, thus producing an even number? I suspect I'm misunderstanding something, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: $2(m+n+1)=2m+2n+2$

Comment: $(2n)+(2m+1)\neq2(m+n+1)$ instead $(2n)+(2m+1)=2(m+n)+1$

Comment: Ahhh i see, thanks Tito and Vlad!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Associativity does not mean "move the parentheses wherever you want".

Note that associativity is the axiom that $(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)$.

If you tried rewriting $2(m+n)+1$ in the way you suggest, you would first have to reduce $2(m+n)+1$ to $(2m + 2n)+1$ by the distributive property,

which would stop you from writing the expression as $2(m + n + 1)$.